# When runtime modifications are written to Edits log file in Name Node, is the Edits Log file getting updated on RAM or Local Disk

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata

When run-time modifications are written to Edits log file in Name Node, is the Edits Log file getting updated on RAM or Local Disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is both. First on the disk and then on the RAM.

To start with, edits log is a logical entity, whereas in the real case it can be many files spread across (called as segments), with a naming convention similar to "edits_xxxxxxxxxxx", each of which represents a particular action (called as transaction) done in HDFS such as append file, delete file, etc.,

Edits file/segment is updated first (on the disk) and then the in-memory (in RAM) metadata of the NN is updated. Thereafter this in-memory data will be served to the needy clients.

Courtesy: Hadoop - The definitive guide.

Comment: Thanks Marco. So what would be the "time interval" when these Edits log file from disk is updated to RAM?

Comment: The usage of the term "time-interval" seems quite out-of-scope in this context, since this has to be a synchronous operation/activity.  We cannot predict when would be the next request from a hadoop client, for that particular file (whose transaction was recorded just now and meta-data updated in-memory). Scenarios such as a sequence of file writes immediately-followed-by file reads (for the same files written just now) are quite common. Hope this throws some light.

Comment: Thank you very much Marco. So I believe Edits log file is updated streaming from disk to RAM. Am I correct

Comment: Yes, disk to RAM should be via one of the (Java) streaming mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks Marco and I really Appreciate your help.